# Append new records base on date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a Combine table which I delete every day and add all the records again. I would like have a Append only records newer than the last date.

The MS Access query is:

```
INSERT INTO combine ( date_c, purpose_F, login_name, channel_name_F, FCR_A, source, date_update, FCR_2G, FCR_W, [Year], [Month], [Day], quarter, [counter], agent_name, sup )
SELECT Fcr_all.date_c, Fcr_all.purpose, Fcr_all.login_name, Fcr_all.channel_name, Fcr_all.FCR_A, "FCR" AS source, Date() AS CURDATE, Fcr_all.FCR_2G, Fcr_all.FCR_W, Year([date_c]) AS Y, Month([date_c]) AS M, Day([date_c]) AS D, DatePart('q',[date_c]) AS Q, "1" AS [count], Roster.agent_name, Roster.Supervisor
FROM Fcr_all LEFT JOIN Roster ON Fcr_all.login_name = Roster.tCAM;
```

I their a way to append records newer than the last date. The records date field is ***date_c***

Example 
I have:
256 records from 4/1/2015,
800 records from 4/2/2015,
500 records from 4/3/2015,

-> i will like to append 900 records from 4/4/2015 and 4/5/2015

What is the easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `WHERE` clause that filters `date_c` so it is greater than the max `date_c` in `combine`.

```
INSERT INTO combine ( date_c, purpose_F, login_name, channel_name_F, FCR_A, source, date_update, FCR_2G, FCR_W, [Year], [Month], [Day], quarter, [counter], agent_name, sup )
SELECT Fcr_all.date_c, Fcr_all.purpose, Fcr_all.login_name, Fcr_all.channel_name, Fcr_all.FCR_A, "FCR" AS source, Date() AS CURDATE, Fcr_all.FCR_2G, Fcr_all.FCR_W, Year([date_c]) AS Y, Month([date_c]) AS M, Day([date_c]) AS D, DatePart('q',[date_c]) AS Q, "1" AS [count], Roster.agent_name, Roster.Supervisor
FROM Fcr_all LEFT JOIN Roster ON Fcr_all.login_name = Roster.tCAM
WHERE date_c > (select MAX(date_c) from combine)
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing in another query where i have already use the **WHERE** clause can I add another criteria example:
'WHERE (((Csat_all.login_name) Like "srtt-*")) & (Csat_all.date_completed > (select MAX(date_c) from combine);'
 Why is it not working ?

Comment: Replace `&` with `AND`. Also, you're missing a closing parenthesis at the very end.

Comment: I fixed it had to use AND. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you.
I have 2 append queries to the **combine**  table.Each querry when appends names a _field_ called **source** which indicates where the data came from. on the code, I want to add a where clause.
To get the max date from a source of the combine table.
`WHERE (((Csat.date_completed)>(select MAX(date_c) from combine where "combine.source =" & 'CSAT')) AND ((Csat.login_name) Like "srtt-*"));` What is wrong with this code ? I think I got it right.

Comment: The Csat query worked perfect, try to do it with another query and **appends 0 records** here is the SQL code: **WHERE (((Fcr.date_c)>(select MAX(date_c) from combine where "combine.source =" & 'FCR')));** Why ?